# Can we make EM waves not interact with electrons by manipulating the properties of the wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Is there a way to make this happen independent of frequency. Can we change the properties of the wave like amplitude, phase etc to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you mean free or bound electros (like in an atom)? In the latter case, there is polarization, some electronic states only get excited by light that is polarized the right way.

Comment: free electrons in metals.

Comment: Well, you could make the amplitude zero. That should do the trick.

Comment: well the e.m will not exist,I am asking for a wave with a non-zero amplitude.

Answer (score 0):

Electrons are electrically charged, which means **by definition** that they interact with the electromagnetic field.